# HTML/CSS - 100% DIV not lining up a 30% and 70% Child

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand why this doesn't line up the two INPUT elements side by side.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<STYLE>

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</STYLE>


    <DIV STYLE='width:100%;'>
        <INPUT  TYPE=text  size=10 maxlength=10 
                STYLE='width:70%;'>
        <BUTTON STYLE='width:30%; float:right;'
        >Button</BUTTON>
    </DIV>
```

Comment: I really want to -1 you for using UPPERCASE HTML TAGS...

Answer (score 2):

```
input{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
}
```

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/FjL2T/)

Need to remove extra space, padding, border, margin

Answer (score 1):

You did float right.  Float both left and it should work out for you.  Also note that if they have padding/margin around them 70% + 30% + padding/margin may not fit on one line :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<DIV STYLE='width:100%;'>
        <INPUT  TYPE=text  size=10 maxlength=10 
                STYLE='width:70%;float:left;'>
        <BUTTON STYLE='width:30%; float:left;'
        >Button</BUTTON>
    </DIV>
```